# How to mount docker volume into my docker project using compose?

Tags: maven, docker, docker-compose

I have a Maven project. I'm running my Maven builds inside Docker. But the problem with that is it downloads all of the Maven dependencies every time I run it and it does not cache any of those Maven downloads.

I found some work arounds for that, where you mount your local .m2 folder into Docker container. But this will make the builds depend on local setup. What I would like to do is to create a volume (long live) and link/mount that volume to `.m2` folder inside Docker. That way when I run the Docker build for the 2nd time, it will not download everything. And it will not be dependent on environment.

How can I do this with docker-compose?

Comment: you can run `mvn compile` as part of your `docker build` and then you push that image to some registry, whenever you pull the image it has your `.m2` folder cached in it and running builds should be significantly faster

Comment: tx, but then i have to manage another image. And things change,

Comment: the `.m2` folder has to live somewhere for it to move around environments conveniently and my suggestion is making it live in the image to dedup work

Comment: Yes, that would work if you want to have a "frozen" version of all of the dependencies included in the image. The dependencies would be downloaded and/or copied into the image at build time of the image. If you want to persist them at run time, please see my answer for a solution using a data volume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing your exact configuration, I would use something like this...

```
version: "2"

services:
  maven:
    image: whatever
    volumes:
      - m2-repo:/home/foo/.m2/repository

volumes:
  m2-repo:
```

This will create a data volume called `m2-repo` that is mapped to the `/home/foo/.m2/repository` (adjust path as necessary). The data volume will survive up/down/start/stop of the Docker Compose project.

You can delete the volume by running something like `docker-compose down -v`, which will destroy containers and volumes.